# sending synchronization data as sql text, sync framework 1

Tags: .net, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm now inheriting a WCF webservice that synchronizes a sql server 2008 DB with ocassionally connected PDAs that have mssqlCE 3.5 DB via Microsoft Sync Framework 1.0. It is not a big database, but has a fair amount of relations between tables. The deal is that we are trying to synchronize data that spans across multiple tables, and even synchronizing just 1 atomic unit of data (a record that spans across tables) gets outofmemory exceptions on PDA. We tried using data surrogates, which relieved a bit, batching, but then we realized it was failing trying to synchronize 1 record of data.
Is there a way in which I can get synchronization data and transport it as a sql file, then transport it and apply it on PDA and / or server, then fire events if it failed or it succeeded? Our synchronization policy is that PDA wins all times.

Thanks in advance!

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, there's nothing in the API for you to export the changes as SQL statements. 
You can try to intercept the changes in the ChangesSelected event, export the dataset to an XML and use the XML on the the client side to apply changes. but you might still run into the same memory issue if you're loading many records in memory...